# JMeter - How to pass an array into a property variable?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a BeanShell PostProcessor under the setUp Thread Group.
It generates an ArrayList that I want to pass as a system property to the test Thread Groups in the Test Plan.
That array contains the number of threads in the test groups.
What is the syntax? How should I refer an element of that array in the Tread Group "Number of Threads (users)"?

This is what I have in the setUp Thread Group

```
ArrayList users = new ArrayList();
${__setProperty(users, ${users})};
```

This is what I put in the Number of Threads

```
${__P(users).get(0)}
```

It does not work.
Thanks
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the "ArrayList" you can go it using [bsh.shared namespace](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables)

1. In setUp Thread Group put the ArrayList into the "bsh.shared" namespace like:

   ```
   ArrayList users = new ArrayList();
   users.add(5);
   bsh.shared.users=users;
   ```
2. In normal Thread Group you can read the value via [__BeanShell function](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733749-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-I) as:

   ```
   ${__BeanShell(bsh.shared.users.get(0),)}
   ```

However I feel that your test is badly designed and you could get rid of scripting or at least of using arrays.

Comment: Dmitri, Your suggestion does not work. I attached the screenshots. Why do you think it's a bad design? I read a JSON file one time in the setUp Thread Group and pass all arrays of variables to the other thread groups in the test plan.

Comment: My suggestion does work,  your Beanshell PreProcessor in the setUp Thread Group does not work as [PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) are designed for using in conjunction with Samplers, if there is no sampler - the postprocessor is being ignored. Change it to sampler and everything will start working as expected. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more details on using Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri. It really works now! In my real example, I have an HTTP sampler and BeanShell PostProcessor attached to it. Your solution will work in that case as well.